# ASP InStr vs PHP strpos

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have some code that I am converting from ASP to PHP and I came across 
InStr. So i looked up the php equivalent which was strpos. I tested both and when i do
`InStr("E-","E")` I am getting a result of **1**, but with `strpos("E-","E")` I am getting a result of **0** I am stuck on how to get a similar result of InStr in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an InStr function like this:

```
function InStr($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0)
{
    $position = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);

    return ($position !== false) ? $position += 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: what my code is doing is testing to see if the position is greater than zero and your original helped. Thank you soo much